# Refactoring code for fetching JSON path to improve performance and readablilty

Tags: java, json, refactoring

I have the following code being repeatedly called to fetch certain string values from JSON response.

```
String val1 = JsonPath.with(e.getValue()).getAsJsonArray("val1/textSpans")
                .get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString();

String val2 = JsonPath.with(e.getValue()).getAsJsonArray("val2/textSpans")
                .get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString();

String val3 = JsonPath.with(e.getValue()).getAsJsonArray("val3/textSpans")
                .get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString();

String val4 = JsonPath.with(e.getValue()).getAsJsonArray("val4/textSpans")
                .get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString();
```

Would it make sense to refactor it as below or is it overkill :

```
JsonPath path = JsonPath.with(e.getValue());
String val1 = path.getAsJsonArray("val1/textSpans")
                    .get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString();
String val2 = path.getAsJsonArray("val2/textSpans")
                    .get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString();
String val3 = path.getAsJsonArray("val3/textSpans")
                    .get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString();
String val4 = path.getAsJsonArray("val4/textSpans")
                    .get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString();
```

Could it be refactored further so that the val1, val2, val3, and val4 are being passed as parameters to the same method, and returning a String?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work although you may need to test it. This doesn't compile because I didn't have the full context of your application, but you can copy the relevant code to test it.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JsonPath path = JsonPath.with(e.getValue());

        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            values.add(getPath("val" + i, path));
        }
    }

    static String getPath(String value, JsonPath path) {
        return path.getAsJsonArray(value + "/textSpans")
                .get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I corrent understand you...

```
public String getValue(JsonArray array, int index) {

    return array.get(index).getAsJsonObject().get("text").getAsString();

}


getValue(path.getAsJsonArray("val1/textSpans"), 0);
```

now you need an array of your url's, for example in collection.

```
List<String> urls = new ArralyList()<>;
urls.add("val1/textSpans");
urls.add("val2/textSpans");
urls.add("val3/textSpans");
urls.add("val4/textSpans");
```

And now use this

```
StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < urls.size() - 1; i++) {
   values.append(getValue(path.getAsJsonArray(urls.get(i)), 0));
}
```